# Setting NODE_OPTIONS for GCP Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a GCP Cloud Function and also ensure it uses the `--max-http-header-size=` node option, but when trying to set `NODE_OPTIONS` for the deploy returns:

```
Problems:
environment_variables:
environment variable name NODE_OPTIONS is reserved by the system: it cannot be set by users
]
```

I was wondering if anyone knew how to allow values like this to be set for a deploy of a Cloud Function.

Comment: Hi there! I think you may try this approach:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67158368/deploy-firebase-functions-on-node-14-runtime-with-increased-memory

Comment: I'm already using `--env-vars-file` which comes up with the error above. We're not going to be using the web UI to deploy these to different environments as this is all handled by a deploy script using the gcloud CLI. So the option of manually putting them in via the web + re-deploying via the web isn't workable.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an option to set it in the start command in the package.json?

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --max-http-header-size=81000 server.js"
  },
```

Comment: Do you know if Cloud Functions use anything like that?